# How to check whether the value of a attribute starts with a specific string?

Tags: antlr3, stringtemplate

For example, the value of the attribute `<greeting>` is "Hello, world!".

What I want is to check whether the `<greeting>` starts with "Hello", if so, apply template `<response>`.

My string template snippet:

`<if(/*do not know how to write the condition here*/)><greeting:response()><endif>`

Answer (score 1):

The expression you're after violates one of the core principles of the strict model-view separation in StringTemplate. No such expression exists *by design*, so you'll need to place the condition somewhere in your Java code which uses the templates.